# Convergence of Gini index

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, convergence

> Let $\theta(F)=2\int^1_0(t-q_F(t))dt$, where $\displaystyle q_F(t)=\frac{\int_0^tF^{-1}(s)ds}{\int_0^1F^{-1}(s)ds}$.

For discrete distributions I'm assuming that $F^{-1}(s)=\inf\{x:F(x)=s\}$ (the quantile function).

The exercise next defines a discrete distribution function in a strange way.

> Let $F_p$ have probability $p$ at $x=0$ and $1-p$ at $x>0$.

(ipsis verbis from the book) This doesn't seem to be a proper distribution, no?

Then they ask me to

> show $\theta(F_p) \xrightarrow[]{p\rightarrow 0}0$ and $\theta(F_p) \xrightarrow[]{p\rightarrow 1}1 $.

My problem begins immediately at finding $F^{-1}$. It seems to be always zero...

Comment: @gui11aume, any thoughts on this? :P

Comment: See my draft answer. To me, it would make more sense if $q_F$ was defined as $F^{-1}(t)/F^{-1}(1)$, or if the integral was over $t-q_F'$.

Comment: @gui11aume , I don't think I can change them, since they are definitions, from what I could tell. $q_F$ is supposed to be the Lorenz curve. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorenzCurve.html

As to the definition of the $\theta(F)$, it's supposed to be the definition of the Gini coefficient. I don't seem to be able to find a definition similar to the one given in my book. I only get estimators

Comment: @gui11aume I've just checked wiki again, and it seems that 
$\theta(F)=1-2\int^1_0 q_F(t)dt$ which is equal to what I have there.

Comment: I also checked and this seems to be correct. My new answer is reverse engineering the question, but this is the only thing I can come up with. If the weight of $F_0$ is not all on 1, then the property does not hold.

Comment: I think I finally got it. The definition of $F_p$ probably means “at some $x > 0$”. The weight of $F_0$ does not need to be all on 1, it just needs to be on a single value greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $F_p$ is a little strange indeed. After thinking about it, I gather that the only possibility is that $x$ is fixed, so that the variable can take two values: 0 and $x$. In these condtions

$$F_p^{-1}(s) = 
\begin{cases}
  0               & \text{if}\ s < p \\
  x               & \text{if}\ s \geq p. \\
\end{cases}$$

Now $\int_0^1 F_p^{-1}(s) ds = x(1-p)$ and

$$\int_0^t F_p^{-1}(s) ds = \begin{cases}
  0       & \text{if}\ t < p \\
  x(t-p)  & \text{if}\ t \geq p. \\
\end{cases}$$

So $q_F(t) = \frac{t-p}{1-p} 1_{\{t \geq p\}}$ and $\theta(F_p) = p$.